# Unix - Addressing filename with space for script

Tags: bash, sox

I have files `Deep.flac` and `A1 - Rolling In The Deep.flac`

I wrote the script below, however it can only work with `Deep.flac`
It cannot seem to work with filenames with spaces. I am learning unix system though my OSX.

Basically, I am using `sox` to convert my flac to aiff while keeping the name of the files intact.

My Script *convertX2Y.sh*:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Author: Rei Yash Dean
# Copyright: Free
# Script: to convert flac files to aiff using sox; while keeping file name unchanged

for x in *.flac;
do sox $x $(basename $x .flac).aiff;
done
```

The error it returns is:

```
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `The': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can see what happens with your filenames when you add an `echo` between `do` and `sox`.

Answer (score 1):

Put [quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes) around things you want to be treated as single arguments by the program:

```
sox "$x" "$(basename "$x" .flac).aiff"
```

If you use double quotes (like above) then you can use variable references like `$x` inside them. If you use [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes) (`'...'`) then any special characters you use inside them are kept as you wrote them.